# htaccess direct all non-server side file requests to a specific subdirectory

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a templating-based CMS with the following structure:

```
/public_html/admin/
```

^ contains all CMS files and functions, etc.

```
/public_html/user_html/
```

^ is the directory the client accesses with FTP and manages all client side files (i.e. html, javascript, css, jpg, png, etc.) but is disallowed privileges to add server-side files (i.e php etc).

```
/public_html/index.php
```

^ is the root public directory which drives the site/application itself, index.php is the only file in this directory and it processes URI requests and runs the application.

A little further on the system and structure: it is set up so that all html files within `user_html` act as templates/layouts for certain modules of the system - these files have custom tags to output the system functions and the server reads all files and folders from `user_html` when requested and outputs them to the application.

This is all fine and runs a treat. What I am trying to achieve here is to hide the `user_html` for all URL browser requests. So basically all paths within the html pages currently have to be read like so to work:

```
src="/user_html/js/scripts.js",
src="/user_html/css/styles.css"
src="/user_html/images/logo.png"
```

whereas the desired paths for the user/client to input when creating and editing the html pages would be as follows:

```
src="/js/scripts.js"
src="/css/styles.css"
src="/images/logo.png"
```

The client has full control over the directories and files within the `user_html` directory, so therefore all file paths will be forever changing. Basically the browser needs to know all files and the directories in which these files are found reside within `user_html`, however be displayed as if they reside in `public_html`.

If anybody has a simple answer using htaccess to route all URI requests, except for .php files and the `/admin/` directory to `user_html`, or any other thoughts and ideas, that would be greatly appreciated.

I've searched far and wide but cannot find a solution for what I'm after. However I'm sure it's going to be quite a simple RewriteCondition & RewriteRule.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's just some rewrite rules!

If you can accept URLs of the form "js/foo.js", then you just need an .htaccess file in public_html.

```
# everything that's not .php or in /admin goes to user_html.
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/admin(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /user_html/$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Thought so that's perfect!

Comment: Only thing is the paths don't work/aren't found when the first Condition is used **"RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.php$"** it returns a "500 internal server error". It's fine with **"RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f"**. I haven't had time to test further but I will shortly. Thanks for your prompt answer!